# Gradio not deploying my nested application file to hugging face

Tags: huggingface, gradio

I am trying to update my gradio app in hugging face by specifying a different custom app file.

I am using the command

```
 gradio deploy --app-file ./interview/app.py
```

to deploy the app.

But my hugging face space is not able to find the application file. Even though it is present in the nested directory. How can I fix this issue ?

[image]
[image]